# How to remove first time toast when application launch?

Tags: android

I am implementing the Spinner ,My problem is that it show toast when I launch application it show first element .That time I was not selected item from spinner .

I do like this.It show Malaysia first time when app launch.

In string.xml

```
 <string name="country_prompt">choose country</string>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>


<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"

        />
```

On java file

```
setContentView(R.layout.firstactivity);
    sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
                "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you don't want the `Toast` to be displayed the first time the `Activity` runs. `onItemSelected` is run when the `Activity` is created even though the user hasn't actually selected anything.

AFAIK, there is no way to avoid this. However, you can easily set a `boolean` flag in say, `onCreate()` and check that flag in `onItemSelected` to decide to run the code or not then toggle the flag in `onItemSelected`.

So something like this

```
  setContentView(R.layout.firstactivity);
    sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    firstRun = true;   // declare this as a member variable (before onCreate())

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!firstRun)
        {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
                "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {  firstRun = false;  }

    }
```

Comment: can you please help me one more matter ..I need to write text (any thing)reqular interval of time ..because I want to check is device hang or not

Comment: Actually I make application in android using phonegap (getting data from server )reqular interval of time .But that application hang after 10 mins

Comment: So I need to check is every app hang after 30 min if we continuos write or fetch data

Comment: I think I need to used Timer and having sheduleAt fixedrate.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you want to do but if it is taking 10 minutes to get data then you have bigger issues

Comment: No Actually I did socket programming , I got data every second .That why I want to check on native application

Comment: I need to print some text every second , then check if native code hang or not

Comment: Can you help in code level Timer.sheduleAtfixed rate .I need to write on screen ..so what to take textview ?

Comment: What tour experience is application hang if data is coming regularly (with parsing) ? is application hang or still work fine many hours

Comment: If you are doing it correctly in a background `Thread` then no it shouldn't hang

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39580/discussion-between-user944513-and-codemagic)